# CSS3 shadows in IE harden rounded div corners

Tags: css, filter, shadow

When I use only rounded corners on my div, it looks about how I expect in IE9.

```
border-radius: 7px;
```

However, when I add the following line to make a drop shadow, I get an unexpected effect:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#818181', Direction=135, Strength=3);
```

Here's a screenshot of the effect. I'm referring to the ugly little black corners suddenly appended to my light blue div:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/406/blackcorners.png/

How can I get rid of that?

Comment: I cant see any blackcorners.png image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 supports `box-shadow` natively, so there's no need to use the old `filter` style.

If you're using the `filter` for the benefit of older IE versions, then it may be that both shadows are coming into play in IE9, and slightly different, thus causing the weird effect.

My first suggestion is simply to drop the `filter` style. This will mean that versions of IE won't see the box shadow, but it's not really a critical element of the layout.

If that's no good, then I would suggest using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to implement the box shadows for older versions of IE. As a bonus, it'll do the `border-radius` too.

With CSS3Pie, you can use the standard CSS `box-shadow` style in older versions of IE, and not need to worry about the `filter` style. And, to show how it directly answers your question, it will switch itself off automatically in IE9, so you won't get the double shadow effect.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I had botched the box-shadow I tried first, so I just assumed I'd need filter.